# Setting up a private PoA Clique network with puppeth

Tags: go-ethereum, clique

I would like to set-up a new private network using [Clique](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225) as protocol with the help of puppeth.

When configuring the new Genesis block, this question is being asked:

> Which accounts are allowed to seal? (mandatory at least one)

How can I specify an account since it is a new network ?

(in other words are accounts independent from the network ?)

### My Solution (geth 1.6.0)

This is similar to the accepted answer below but allowed me to create multiple sealers/miners (and script those creations)

1. On *any* existing network (PoA or PoW), create new accounts for the "sealers" or use `geth --datadir=/wherever account new` (thanks Péter)
2. Collect from the `keystore` directories the keys of these accounts. For ease of management the files for the keys can be renamed to anything you want, say `ACCOUNT_NUMBER.json` where `ACCOUNT NUMBER` is the hex value of the account e.g. `0x035e19356880f86804b5fbf7015192be271ab8e4`
3. Using `puppeth`, create the `genesis.json` file, and enter in `which accounts`, the list of sealer accounts created above
4. For each sealer node, assuming the data directory for the private network is `MYNET`, create a directory structure `MYNET/keystore` and drop the key for that sealer in the directory
5. Initialize the node *once* : `geth --datadir "MYNET" init genesis.json`
6. Run the node. Unlocking the account and starting the miner should work.

(note: I am not using `puppeth` to create the nodes but use my own docker containers)

### Important !

<s>I am running into [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14408) when initializing the network with more than 3 signers. I will keep this question updated</s>

To have more than 3 signers registered from the start, you must use a 1.6.1-unstable with a last commit > 02fa3e3179011bcbdf9142f9efba8d3a52df898

See the [commit](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/02fa3e3179011bcbdf9142f9efba8d3a52df8987)

### Adding/Removing sealers

Please check [this SE question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15541/how-to-add-new-sealer-in-geth-1-6-proof-of-authority)

Comment: Just a minor correction, the network probably would have self corrected itself with more than 3 miners too if enough are mining to push the thing forward, but the first few blocks caused ugly error messages and failures on the initial mining nodes.

Comment: You can also create new accounts straight from the CLI via `geth --datadir=/wherever account new`.

Comment: @Bruno Grieder It would be nice if you took your answer and made it an answer, rather than putting your answer inside the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new account from other network then import the Keystore file to your private network.

The steps I took was

1. Generate a Genesis.json file of a PoW private network from Puppeth
2. Geth init
3. Geth attach
4. Generate a new account
5. Delete the geth folder in the datadir
6. Use Puppeth to create a new Genesis.json that use Clique and put the address that you've just created in there
7. Unlock the account
8. miner.start() and see the block number goes up :)

Comment: Thanks. I went for a modified version of your workflow. See Edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the extradata field in genesis.json as following:
0x00... (64 zeros at beginning)
accounts stucked, without "0x" and without any spaces
00.. (130 zeros at end)

Answer (score 0):

https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8
Easy steps given in the above link. Just follow

You can Generate Account ID and password then later use any one among them.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It is better to include the main points in the answer and leave the link to fill the details.