# Geth additional condition for valid blocks in private network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-authority

Using Geth and a private blockchain, is there any possibility to specify an additional condition for a block to be valid? In particular, I want to accept only blocks that are mined from miners that are listed in a smart contract. Other blocks should just be ignored. The purpose is to secure a private testnet where the vaild miners change over time (by vote). I think it would also be a good idea, if no miner could mine two consecutive blocks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably a Proof of Authority chain. Essentially, rather than a block being valid or not based on a hash, it's valid or not based on who mined it.

I'm not sure how geth's PoA system works, but Parity has a [PoA](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) mode which allows the creator of the chain to use a contract to specify current authorities.

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to determine which miner may or may not mine the next block in either geth or parity.

Comment: Also geth has their own PoA system https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/setting-up-a-private-poa-clique-network-with-puppeth. Unfortunatelly both are incompatible between them.

Comment: I have looked into PoA (Geth) and it seems to fit my needs. However, it would be nice, if one could specify additional constraints for blocks to be vaild.