# Clique: New added signers won't show up on other nodes and mining new blocks stopped

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority, clique

I have followed following answer about [How to add new Sealer in Geth 1.6 Proof of Authority?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15779/4575).

Currently I have one signer account `0x4e4a0750350796164d8defc442a712b7557bf282`. With one signer the mining was working without any problem. My signer account proposed a new signer account using `propose()` function.

```
clique.propose("0x5b29ede59ecff473fb5760a53dbacc21cbc5b3dd", true)
```

On my signer node and other nodes, I can see the new address on my signers list (`clique.getSigners()`),

```
clique.getSigners()
["0x4e4a0750350796164d8defc442a712b7557bf282", "0x5b29ede59ecff473fb5760a53dbacc21cbc5b3dd"]
```

Than on my other node which has `0x5b29ede59ecff473fb5760a53dbacc21cbc5b3dd` I have unlocked that account and run `miner.start()` command, but no help on mining new blocks on the network. So network stop mining new blocks :(

Also new signer account does not show up on my other connected node, which has the account for new added signer.

Now, I cannot also remove the newly added signer using:

```
clique.propose("0x5b29ede59ecff473fb5760a53dbacc21cbc5b3dd", false)
```

Please note that both signers are unlocked and `miner.start()` is active.

**[Q]** How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I mean instead of `"0x"`, there is original ethereum address. And another node that address is unlocked and I run miner.start() command but still mining new blocks is stopped. @ivicaa

Comment: Is "0x5b29ede59ecff473fb5760a53dbacc21cbc5b3dd" also eth.coinbase? I am not 100% sure, but I remeber having problems when the sealer account is not eth.coinbase.

Comment: No it is not; let me make it `coinbase` and see will there be any change. @ivicaa

Comment: Ah I feel like a stupid, eth.coinbase was pointing some other address, when I updated with "0x5b29ede59ecff473fb5760a53dbacc21cbc5b3dd" it get solved. @ivicaa

Comment: How could I remove new added signer? @ivicaa

Comment: Both accounts have to send clique.propose(..., false). You always need 50% + 1 vote, which is 2 for 2 accounts.

Comment: It didn't work :( before remove a signer, again each account should be assigned to coinbase, again? or is there any default account for the clique as well? @ivicaa

Comment: It worked! But it does not right away show up on the clique.getSigners() @ivicaa

Comment: I assume it has to be eth.coinbase. I am again not 100% sure, but It might take some blocks until the request is processed. Where I am 100% sure is that both have to vote false for the address which is to be removed.

Comment: You are right, I think it takes around 10 blocks to be show up on the `clique.getSigners()` @iviaa

Comment: Yes. They‘ll calling that snapshots or so, but I don‘t know the design rationale behind it.

Comment: If there is 10 signer accounts on the same node and all are unlocked. How can each can do propose? I can ask this on a different question. @ivicaa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73880/discussion-between-ivicaa-and-alper).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eth.coinbase` has to point to the sealing account.

If you want to remove again the second account, both accounts will have to propose the removal. You always need 50% + 1 vote, which is 2 for 2 accounts.