# How can we add new nodes under PoA?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, proof-of-authority

I implemented a PoA system successfully. But after the initial setup (eg two nodes), how are new nodes added? I understand that the acceptance of a new node is a voting process but I am not certain how that is implemented.

Here is the link I used for the setup - 
https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

Output from machine 2 (which has nodes 3,4). Nodes 1,2 are on machine 1 and they both are signers. It shows on node 3 that the account is unlocked but it is not authorised.

> more nohup.out  INFO [04-14|17:22:17] Maximum peer count
>   ETH=25 LES=0 total=25 INFO [04-14|17:22:17] Starting peer-to-peer node
>   instance=Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4 INFO
>   [04-14|17:22:17] Allocated cache and file handles
>   database=/home/satoshimaca/blockchain2/node3/geth/chaindata cache=7 68
>   handles=512 INFO [04-14|17:22:18] Initialised chain configuration
>   config="{ChainID: 1515 Homestead: 1 DAO:  DAOSupport: false EI
>   P150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople:  Engine:
>   clique}" INFO [04-14|17:22:18] Initialising Ethereum protocol
>   versions="[63 62]" network=1515 INFO [04-14|17:22:18] Loaded most
>   recent local header          number=0 hash=fdb68b…8a634f td=1 INFO
>   [04-14|17:22:18] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0
>   hash=fdb68b…8a634f td=1 INFO [04-14|17:22:18] Loaded most recent local
>   fast block      number=0 hash=fdb68b…8a634f td=1 INFO [04-14|17:22:18]
>   Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0 INFO
>   [04-14|17:22:18] Regenerated local transaction journal
>   transactions=0 accounts=0 INFO [04-14|17:22:18] Starting P2P
>   networking  INFO [04-14|17:22:20] UDP listener up
>   self=enode://7b13a6dc2fd5de476b2a579d702a36ec37587dad1cef7f99501835
>   4928a279a7733635e3cbd3b2fa1a261c2b37638f2aa46195bc7e1ebfa3c1875c84ecbc8087@[::]:30313
>   INFO [04-14|17:22:20] RLPx listener up
>   self=enode://7b13a6dc2fd5de476b2a579d702a36ec37587dad1cef7f99501835
>   4928a279a7733635e3cbd3b2fa1a261c2b37638f2aa46195bc7e1ebfa3c1875c84ecbc8087@[::]:30313
>   INFO [04-14|17:22:20] IPC endpoint opened
>   url=/home/satoshimaca/blockchain2/node3/geth.ipc INFO [04-14|17:22:20]
>   HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://localhost:8503
>   cors= vhosts=local host INFO [04-14|17:22:21] Unlocked account
>   address=0xC08832c6cB6df14340F3866B293a705FB9bc378B INFO
>   [04-14|17:22:21] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1 INFO
>   [04-14|17:22:21] Etherbase automatically configured
>   address=0xC08832c6cB6df14340F3866B293a705FB9bc378B INFO
>   [04-14|17:22:21] Starting mining operation  INFO [04-14|17:22:21]
>   Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0
>   elapsed=226.085µs WARN [04-14|17:22:21] Block sealing failed
>   err=unauthorized

Here is the connection for node 3 -

> nohup geth --datadir node3/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30313 --rpc
>   --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8503 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,ne t,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes
>   'enode://601ade737b81f16abdd0ce9983b63eb12050c4ef89c46b8fdbf3e3e6c951cc02dffe36f87200033107cf8b00
>   7355e780fba16b67d1d46603b1321f07314ea46b@10.132.0.2:30310' --networkid
>   1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock 'c08832c6cb6df14340f3866b293a70
>   5fb9bc378b' --password node3/pwdnode3.txt --mine &

Geth on node 1 gives these peers and this enode -

```
> admin
```

> {   datadir: "/home/satoshimaca/blockchain/node1",   nodeInfo: {
>       enode: "enode://64793e6e791115d315550d651cda00342b688ba36728b3d8070b04f4513ff65eb15ffb8f66387f1733340d8732e6ca956f0825cd3fc4e67686e04f63c5d0abc4@[::]:30311",
>       id: "64793e6e791115d315550d651cda00342b688ba36728b3d8070b04f4513ff65eb15ffb8f66387f1733340d8732e6ca956f0825cd3fc4e67686e04f63c5d0abc4",
>       ip: "::",
>       listenAddr: "[::]:30311",
>       name: "Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4",
>       ports: {
>         discovery: 30311,
>         listener: 30311
>       },
>       protocols: {
>         eth: {
>           config: {...},
>           difficulty: 15290,
>           genesis: "0x702d8ca9647d171a6596a775888f71c7c0f3ddb011fbffcb921be685b2ef33b7",
>           head: "0x574671023088dd06c2127cee4e2a70e30782ed3f525d28b537294ac0f3297099",
>           network: 1515
>         }
>       }   },   peers: [{
>         caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
>         id: "d889d565b3ddc37491d131aed1c23d0a7b30a185bb925f325c7830b2ae710bc127010487f39f32d889afd1284ea31aa893adddda2197f2763485926970620381",
>         name: "Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4",
>         network: {
>           inbound: true,
>           localAddress: "127.0.0.1:30311",
>           remoteAddress: "127.0.0.1:54108",
>           static: false,
>           trusted: false
>         },
>         protocols: {

From node 1 - acct 1 is definitely a signer and it is unlocked but then is not authorised.

```
> clique.getSigners()
```

> ["0xc08832c6cb6df14340f3866b293a705fb9bc378b",
>   "0xfc1bdf06d1150e6eeeb229a8500b09df8ccdcbbd",
>   "0xfcad53c780a4f6c66b3daca331fe72fc6559c367"]

Comment: I did more checking and found that votes are needed which appears to be a manual process. But I am unsure once the decision is made about who will have a new master node or mining node then how that is implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a new node as sealer is simple as calling:

`clique.propose(<NEWSEALER>, true)`

You will need 50% + 1 votes.

See [How to add new Sealer in Geth 1.6 Proof of Authority?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15541/how-to-add-new-sealer-in-geth-1-6-proof-of-authority) for more details.

For the details on the specification see EIP 225 -  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225

Comment: If the nodes are on different machines in google cloud, how can the signing node know about the other accounts? I had the issue before when the listAccounts only showed some of the accounts under PoW. Will the signer know about all the accounts due to the bootnode?

Comment: He doesn't need to know if the proposed sealer account actually exists. It's simply proposing an address.

Comment: I added clique.propose and it shows in clique.proposals. It just sits in proposals. I did the proposal on the two signing nodes. How is the proposal now approved? Is there a clique.approve equivalent?

Comment: After your both sealers have called the function than you habe to wait few blocks till it takes effect.

Comment: I can connect now from the remote node but it states unauthorised when I attempt to mine. I can use the initial machine which has nodes1,2 but node3 remotely does not work. Is there any diagnostics tool to use? Geth on the initial machine shows 2 peers.

Comment: Your sealer account has to be eth.coinbase and it has to be unlocked. Moreover, you should query via clique object who the sealers are.

Comment: I added some geth output in the question as an edit. I added clique and then the address and the proposals were cleared (I assume accepted). There must be a way to check what proposals were accepted.

Comment: I think I have it - clique.getSigners. I am just checking now.