# How to configure extraData field in genesis file

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, genesis, enode

I am in the process of setting up a private, permissioned Quorum blockchain with Istanbul consensus for simple use cases. When I specify the number of validators when generating the genesis file it works as expected.

But how can I add validators dynamically? For example I have generated genesis file with two validators and it is up and running. Now if I want to add a new node as validator how I should configure? If I use the same genesis file and added new node's enode address to permissioned-list it is connecting successfully but getting unsealed signature error. Do I need to modify the genesis file extraHash field for new nodes?

Comment: Answered in this thread...
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15541/how-to-add-new-sealer-in-geth-1-6-proof-of-authority

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/650, it should address all of the questions you pose.