# Unable to Add 3rd Proof-of-Authority Sealer Node

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, proof-of-authority, poa, clique

I have a geth POA private blockchain setup and running with 2 sealer nodes. Now I have setup a 3rd node as a sealer, and ran the following command on the both existing sealer nodes

```
clique.propose("0x555c9e3d738837d14ebda7cad9359f840f3c650c", true)
> null
```

and we confirm that the 3rd node has been voted because we see the address of the 3rd node when we run `clique.getSigners()` along with the other two sealer nodes' address.

**Problem:** However after we start and restart the 3rd geth node that we are trying to add as a sealer node, we get the error

> INFO [08-24|21:25:55.169] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=e935f6…e90182 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=256.472µs
>
> WARN [08-24|21:25:55.170] Block sealing failed                     err=unauthorized

This error persists even when running `clique.propose(...,true)` on the 3rd node to for itself.

On Ethstats, we see that this 3rd node is stuck at block #0 and never tries to sync the blockchaibn.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you run genesis init for the 3rd node?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to MINE the network before it actually synced up to become a validator node, so I'd sync it up first til that block when it becomes a validator and re-run the node with miner on settings to seal blocks. At block 1, it cannot be a validator based on genesis file.
Also make sure you specify bootnodes correctly to your node